# Rotating elements in an svg at different angles

Tags: svg, rotation

I'm trying to create an svg where when you hover over one element in the image it triggers different animations on other parts of the image.

Example here: https://codepen.io/SHINZOC/pen/GRgXeey

Looking to have the pink rectangle disappear when hovering over while also having each square rotate at different angles. I can get one square to rotate but the others won't for some reason. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
.pink_rectangle { transition: .3s;}
.pink_rectangle:hover {opacity: 0;}
#pink_rectangle:hover + #blue_square {
transform: rotate(45deg);
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box:fill-box;
 }
#pink_rectangle:hover + #yellow_square {
transform: rotate(35deg);
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box:fill-box;
 }

#pink_rectangle:hover + #orange_square {
transform: rotate(15deg);
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box:fill-box;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet possible to do what you ask with plain css you would need to use `addEventListener("mouseover", function());` in javascript to make it work.

It doesn't work because CSS can't affect other css classes that are not contained within it.

If you don't know how to use `addEventListener` read a bit of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).